# How to upload big files to webserver?

Tags: delphi, file-upload, webserver

My application needs to send big files (>2GB) to a webserver. I tried to receive the file with a php script on server side, but the file size exceeds the php limit. Sadly, my server hoster does not allow me to increase the file size limit that much.

So, it seems the only possible solution is using FTP. But when using FTP, I need to store the credentials in the source code and someone could reverse engineer my software and get the credentials.

I didn't find any suitable and safe solution for this. Can someone give me a hint how this should be done?

Comment: Can you create a separate, dedicated FTP account? Some hosters allow it.

Comment: I can create a separate user and restrict the access to only 1 directory, yes. But the problem is still the same. Every user would have full access to this directory and the files of other users are unsecure.

Comment: You should create an FTP account per user, but maybe you have too many users for that. Another way is to use PHP and upload the file chunk by chunk (for instance 64KB). You will need to write some code for that but it will work.

Comment: Yeah, manually creating an FTP account for each user is way to complex to handle for many users. But I like your idea of splitting the file into chunks. Didn't think about this and I definitely give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: You could also make the FTP account ‘write only’ so nobody can read the files of others, just like the webserver upload. When sending large files, using ftp to send them, will be faster!